# How do I implement remember me functionality in Oauth 2.0 with refresh_token?

Tags: javascript, c#, security, oauth-2.0

I have read a lot of material, including the OAuth 2.0's RFC, to make a secure login using this protocol. The flow that I have implemented is the authorization code grant, because I have a secure NET CORE back-end to store the client secret. I have implemented the protocol as it is described in the RFC or in other Oauth 2.0 implementation workflow sheets.

At the moment I have the access_token and the refresh_token, but I desire to implement the remeber me functionality. I thinked it in different ways, but I don't figure out how to implement it in a secure way.

If I will save the refresh in the browser's http security cookies through the server, I'm vulnerable to the CSRF attack, and if I will save it in local storage is even worse because I'm vulnerable to XSS attacks and it can be stolen.

In simple words I need to mitigate the XSS and CSRF vulnerabilities, having a remember me functionality. (I also thinked about using browsers' same-site cookie attribute, to mitigate se CSRF vulnerability, but I need to get back-to-back compatibility and this feature is only available in the recent version of the browsers).

My question is: How do I implement remember me functionality also taking care of security aspects?

Comment: How are your browser to backend requests authorized now (after OAuth2 login)? Do you use a cookie identifying a backend session or a token that is always sent with a request (where is the token stored)? Is your security model of an authenticated session stronger than the model for the "remember me" functionality (using a cookie or localStorage)?

Comment: My client app running on the browser in Vue JS, store the access_token in a global variable inside the code an then use it on every request to the resource server (I don't use either local storage or cookie). Infact every time the page is refreshed the token is erased and a new login is requested to the user. If I find the way to securely store the refresh_token, even using other security mecanisms othen than simply save the refresh_token, my app isn't vulnerable to attacks.

Answer (score 0):

If your application has an XSS vulnerability, then it doesn't matter whether you keep a token in-memory (variable) or in localStorage. The malicious code will not have a problem accessing it. So I think keeping a "remember me" info in localStorage doesn't degrade your current security level. To protect your application against XSS attacks, you can use things like Content Security Policy, so that only the JavaScript code you trust will be executed. For more info, see the [OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md).

I think you could keep your access token in sessionStorage instead of a variable so users don't have to log in when they reload the page.

If you store the "remember me" info in an HTTP-only cookie, it may make your application vulnerable to CSRF attacks, but again, there are ways to prevent it ([OWASP CSRF prevention](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md)) such as CORS and sending a extra token in each request, which needs to be read from a cookie by JavaScript code.

The "remember me" functionality may add some kind of risk, since users stay logged in for a long time. So it's up to you to assess the balance between the risks and convenience for users.

You can take a look at the [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-00). It doesn't discuss the "remember me" functionality, but it discusses good practices and security considerations.

Comment: You pointed out to me that now I am possibly vulnerable to XSS regarding the access_token, but keep in mind that in the OAuth2.0 protocol is specified that the access_token has to be short living, so regarding how to store it, is less important than the refresh_token. So the refresh_token is more important than the access_token, so my model security for this must be stronger. Regarding the documents that you pointed me out, I have already give a simple read but I simply ask if someone has already had experiences how to save it in a secure way.

Comment: OK, if you find something interesting, please post it as an answer. You can check [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/40145/201385) and [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/64/201385) answer from security.stackexchange.com.